# 2 errors when booting kernel

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, x86-64

I'm trying to make my own OS but the kernel won't boot, [and I'm getting 2 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZq2K.png):

> Error: no multiboot header found.
> Error: you need to load the kernel first.

I know basically nothing about assembly, I just followed a tutorial, so I have no idea what it means.

header.asm:

```
section .multiboot_header
header_start:
    ; magic number
    dd 0xe85250d6 ; multiboot2
    ; architecture
    dd 0 ; protected mode i386
    ; header length
    dd header_end - header_start
    ; checksum
    dd 0x100000000 - (0xe85250d6 + 0 + (header_end - header_start))

    ; end tag
    dw 0
    dw 0
    dd 8
header_end:
```

linker.ld:

```
ENTRY(start)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 1M;

    .boot :
    {
        KEEP(*(.multiboot_header))
    }

    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
    }
}
```

Makefile:

```
x86_64_asm_source_files := $(shell find src/impl/x86_64 -name *.asm)
x86_64_asm_object_files := $(patsubst src/impl/x86_64/%.asm, build/x86_64/%.o, $(x86_64_asm_source_files))

$(x86_64_asm_object_files): build/x86_64/%.o : src/impl/x86_64/%.asm
    mkdir -p $(dir $@) && \
    nasm -f elf64 $(patsubst build/x86_64/%.o, src/impl/x86_64/%.asm, $@) -o $@

.PHONY: build-x86_64
build-x86_64: $(x86_64_asm_object_files)
    mkdir -p dist/x86_64 && .
    x86_64-elf-ld -n -o dist/x86_64/kernel.bin -T targets/x86_64/linker.ld $(x86_64_asm_object_files)
    cp dist/x86_64/kernel.bin targets/x86_64/iso/boot/kernel.bin && \
    grub-mkrescue /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc -o dist/x86_64/kernel.iso targets/x86_64/iso
```

I've searched on stackoverflow but I didn't find anything that worked for me. I tried a few but it still gave me the same error message every time.

Comment: grub doesn't do 64 bit.